# iOS Swift code freezes with NSURL when sent from foreground to background to foreground again with 100% loss connection

Tags: ios, swift

I have been developing with Swift for 6 months so a new user. The app I'm working on has a focus on poor connections and slow speeds. My app freezes under the following conditions.

I have a JSON query to get data from my server, it uses NSURL / NSData. If I have a connection it works, if I have no connection it fails as expected and I report an error to the user that there is no connection. But:

If the connection has 100% loss (you can simulate this via the developer settings within the phone, Network Link Conditioner) the query runs and my app shows an activity indicator. You then press the home button to put the app into background and then click the app icon to open it again. The activity screen is still displayed but the display is frozen. The activity indicator doesn't spin and the battery icon and clock update but draw on top of each other (there is no refresh whatsoever).

After another 30 seconds or so the app terminates. I expect watchdog is killing the app due to the freeze.

If I run the same process with my phone connected to Xcode the app doesn't terminate. I assume watchdog doesn't kill tasks when running via Xcode.

This may seen like a rare occurrence but I would like to try a catch this bug / freeze in my code but as I cannot get an errors displayed it is very hard to do.

Has anyone seen this before? Do you know the cause?

EDIT
Fails with sending or receiving data via JSON, as my sending code is simpler here is the code:

```
func sendSeverV2(theUrl: String, parameters: String) -> String {

    // build the url for a GET request
    var status = "OK"    
    let parameters2 = parameters.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

    let urlWithParams = "\(theUrl)?\(parameters2)"
    let myUrl         = NSURL(string: urlWithParams)
    let data          = NSData(contentsOfURL: myUrl!)

    guard data != nil else {
        return "Error"
    }

    do {
        let object = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

        if let jsonData = object as? [String: AnyObject]
        {
            status = jsonData["Status"] as! String
        }
        } catch {
            // report error

        }

    if status == "Error"
    {
        print(" JSON fetch had an error for \(urlWithParams)")
    }

    return status

}
```

EDIT: This function is used for many calls back to the server. Some run on a non main thread. But there are cases when I have this on the main thread. My reason (which may be due to my inexperience) is I may have a settings screen where the user can opt-in or opt-out of email alerts. I need to ensure that the user knows that the the settings have been applied. It would not be good for the user to opt-out of an email alert for the server call to fail but the user thinks it worked. So in these cases the user may have to wait a few seconds on a slow connection or wait for a timeout on a 100% loss connection so the app can display, "connection error".

Comment: It would be useful if you could include some of the code that you are using in the post as well.

Comment: added code, could not get the func part of the code to appear in the editor correctly, it's in the body of the question, may be someone can edit / fix for me?

Comment: What's your approach for threading? Which threads runs the above code? How do you communicate with the main thread?

Comment: Apple documentation about [dataWithContentsOfURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:) says: *Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated. Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler: method of the NSURLSession class.*